# Unable to find a specification for `Firebase

Tags: xcode, firebase, cocoapods

I got problem with the installation of Firebase on Xcode for a swift application.

I got this error:

> pod Unable to find a specification for `Firebase (>= 2.5.0)`

My Podfile is this one:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '8.0'
# Uncomment this line if you're using Swift
use_frameworks!

pod 'Firebase', '>= 2.5.0'
target 'banana' do

end

target 'bananaTests' do

end

target 'bananaUITests' do

end
```

I don't know why because I followed each step of the tutorial from Firebase.

Comment: i find basically re-installing cocoapods can help with that annoying problem

Comment: What version of cocoapods are you using?

Comment: When I just write
pod 'Firebase' I got an error too "Unable to find a specification for `Firebase`"
I got the version 2.0.0 of cocoapods

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try removing the specific version information, simply:

```
pod 'Firebase'
```

And if that doesn't work, try forcing your local pod spec repo to update Firebase by typing this on the command line from the root of the project:

```
pod update Firebase
```

Comment: When I just write pod 'Firebase' I got an error too "Unable to find a specification for Firebase"

Comment: I just added another idea to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you make sure you run

```
pod setup
pod install
```

it worked for me. Make sure you don't open the Podfile with the default Texteditor installed in Mac it will mess up your sigle quote. Open it only with Xcode.